# Matrix solution with Numpy: no solution?

Tags: python, numpy

Ran a simple script in Numpy to solve a system of 3 equations:

```
from numpy import *
a = matrix('1 4 1; 4 13 7; 7 22 13')
b = matrix('0;0;1')
print linalg.solve(a,b)
```

But when I ran it through the command prompt, I somehow got:

```
[[  3.46430741e+15]
 [ -6.92861481e+14]
 [ -6.92861481e+14]]
```

although Wolfram Alpha says there's no solution.

Does anyone know why there seems to be this difference between the Numpy/WRA answers?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=WRA What on earth is WRA?

Comment: @Josh `WRA == Wolfram Alpha`

Comment: @KDawG Ahh gotcha. I don't think I've ever seen that acronym. It would probably be better to refer to the computational system as Mathematica (the brains behind "WRA"). `The first was Mathematica—the system in which all of Wolfram|Alpha is implemented.` http://www.wolframalpha.com/about.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take pen and paper (or use `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`) and calculate the ranks of the coefficient and the augmented matrix you'll see that, according to [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem), there is no solution. So Wolfram is right.

NumPy searches for numerical solution of equation using LU decomposition. Without going into details [LU decomposition](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/lu.pdf) involves divisions, divisions in FP arithmetic can lead to significant errors.

If you check:

```
a = np.matrix('1 4 1; 4 13 7; 7 22 13')
b = np.matrix('0;0;1')

c = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
np.linalg.norm(a * c - b)
## 2.0039024427351748
```

you'll see that NumPy solution is far from being correct.